# C# .NET Core API returning corrupt image when running in Azure

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, redis, png

Currently running into an issue with an API which takes a PDF file and converts it into a .png image. This code is running perfectly fine locally, and I always get the entire page correctly converted - however once it's deployed to Azure, I seem to be getting a corrupt image returned. I'll add some sample images below at the bottom of the post so that you're able to see what I mean.

I'm using the Docnet core library (https://github.com/GowenGit/docnet) to do this conversion. I have a service which uses the library, and returns a byte array which I then return from my controller method, as follows:

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("pdfs/{customerId}/{pageNum}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetCustomerPdf(string customerId, int pageNum)
        {
            var customerPng = await _customerPdfService.GetPdfPage(customerId, pageNum);
            return File(customerPng, "image/png");
        }
```

Inside my service, I'm following the example code from the Docnet Github repository, with the exception that I'm caching PDFs and images in a Redis cache instance in order to avoid having to reprocess or redownload the PDF if we don't have to.

```
        public async Task<byte[]> GetPdfPage(string customerId, int pageNumber)
        {
            var imageBytes = await _redisCache.GetAsync(GenerateRedisKeyPdfPage(customerId, pageNumber));
            if(imageBytes != null) return imageBytes;

            var bytes = await GetPdf(customerId);

            var pdfPageImage = GetPageImageFromPdf(bytes, pageNumber);
            await SaveToRedis(pdfPageImage, GenerateRedisKeyPdfPage(customerId, pageNumber));

            return pdfPageImage;
        }
```

The GetPdf method simply uses a WebClient to download the pdf file bytes from our file store - it also caches the PDF's bytes in Redis. This is fairly simple, so I won't paste this method unless someone asks to see it. Below is the `GetPageImageFromPdf` method. This is mostly the same as the Docnet example. The `_docLib` variable comes from a dependency injected singleton which houses the `DocLib.Instance` as specified in the documentation from Docnet.

```
        private byte[] GetPageImageFromPdf(byte[] pdfBytes, int pageNumber)
        {
            var docReader = _docLib.GetDocReader(pdfBytes, new PageDimensions(1080, 1920));
            var pageReader = docReader.GetPageReader(pageNumber);

            var rawBytes = pageReader.GetImage();

            var width = pageReader.GetPageWidth();
            var height = pageReader.GetPageHeight();

            var bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

            AddBytes(bmp, rawBytes);

            var stream = new MemoryStream();

            bmp.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);

            return stream.ToArray();
        }

        private static void AddBytes(Bitmap bmp, byte[] rawBytes)
        {
            var rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);

            var bmpData = bmp.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);
            var pNative = bmpData.Scan0;

            Marshal.Copy(rawBytes, 0, pNative, rawBytes.Length);
            bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
        }
```

I get the feeling this issue is not caused by the Docnet library, as I have tried removing the Redis cache set operation on the codebase deployed to Azure and generating the PNG locally - then I saved that byte array to the same Redis instance so that the Azure app picks up a correctly generated .png byte array, however even when we do this, and we know for certain that the cached bytes are correct, a corrupt file is still returned from Azure.

Image examples:

[Corrupt image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EEyU.png)

[Non-corrupt, generated in local environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dB8RU.png)

It seems like only the top portion of the image is being served, the rest of the image is just not present. Depending on the PNG viewer you use it'll either stretch the image to the correct size, or else just show a blank bottom section of the image.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Are you running on Linux or Windows in Azure?  And locally?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Running on a Linux P1v2 instance in Azure. Have also tried on a P2v2 instance to check if it was a memory/CPU constraint. Locally I'm on macOS.